# How to share a web application ( php-mysql ) among two computers connected via an ad-hoc Wi-Fi network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, web-application

I pretty much dont know anything about networking . But I had previously connected two computers ( 1 laptop and the other a desktop ) using a LAN cable at my workplace .

I access a php-mysql app hosted on a wamp server in the desktop through the IP address of the network . But recently I had to move the PC to another room so the cable length became an issue .

The desktop computer does not have a built-in wireless card , so I'm thinking whether it will be possible to achieve the same thing by installing a USB WiFi Router on the desktop and setting up an ad-hoc Wi-Fi connection . I've heard that sharing of files are possible via the ad-hoc connection but I don't know whether a web application hosted on 1 computer can be accessed on the other through this setup .

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to work on an application you are building, whether on pc1 or pc2, right?

- START menu, right-click on My Computer, properties: Edit Workgroup
  and assign it a name.Do this on pc1 and pc2. The same Workgroup Name for both PC's.
- Then on any pc select a folder, then right-click on it, Share,
  Share. You want to share with Workgroup or Homegroup; depending on
  which Win OS you have, you'd set up one or the other.
- But it's a good idea to make the Workgroup the same on both pc's. You
  might want to reboot too after also.
- Then to get to the folder you just shared go to My Computer -> Network,
  and select the shared folder. You can make a shortcut to the folder too.
- For Sharing solutions, you will have to also describe in the properties of the Share Folder; if you want to allow Read, Write, Execute via right click on the Shared Folder, Share Tab, Advanced Share, then select which network
  users have sharing and whether they have read/write/execute.

That's all there is to it. I do it all the time between my PC, laptop, my phone, and my PS4.